# How to calculate mod of number with big exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I want to find

$$
5^{133} \mod 8.
$$
I have noticed that $5^n \mod 8 = 5$ when $n$ is uneven and 1 otherwise, which would lead me to say that $5^{133} \mod 8 = 5$ But I don't know how to prove this. How can I prove that this is the case (or find another solution if it is not)?

Comment: Hint: $\bmod 8\!:\  \color{#c00}{5^{\large 2}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, 5^{\large 2n}\equiv (\color{#c00}{5^{\large 2}})^{\large n}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large n}\equiv 1\ \ $

Comment: What does the triple equal sign mean?

Comment: 25 leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by 8 so it means they are "equivalent" under mod 8

Comment: @Sandi this is the common way to write congruences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all it is easy to see that $5^2\equiv 1$ (mod $8$). We also know that $133=66\times 2+1$.  Hence

$5^{133}\equiv 5^{2\times 66+1}\equiv 5\times (5^2)^{66}\equiv 5\times 1^{66}\equiv 5$ (mod $8$).

Comment: Should the first triple-equal sign on the second row not be a normal equal sign? And the second one too?

Comment: Yes, you can also write regular equality there. But if two numbers are equal in $\mathbb{Z}$ then they are also congruent mod $n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and because we only care about congruence here I decided to write congruence from the beginning.

Comment: I don't understand how you do the step $5 \times (5^2)^{66} \equiv 5 \times 1^{66} (\mathrm{mod} 8)$. Could you clarify please?

Comment: $5^2\equiv 1$(mod $8$), hence $(5^2)^{66}\equiv 1^{66}\equiv 1$(mod $8$). That's it. It all follows from a basic theorem on modular arithmetic: that if $a\equiv b$(mod $n$) and $c\equiv d$(mod $n$) then $ab\equiv cd$(mod $n$). In other words multiplication mod $n$ is well defined. (same thing can we said about sum mod $n$)

Comment: I found a similar thing in my book, but it said that $ac \equiv bd (modn)$. Did you make a typo or is it a different theorem?

Comment: @Sandi oh yes, of course it is $ac\equiv bd$(mod $n$). Was a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"Highbrow method":

If you undertake to learn any *number theory* , there is Euler's theorem:   $$a^{\varphi (n)}\cong1\pmod n$$, for $a$ *relatively prime* to $n$.

($\varphi$ is Euler's totient function,  and just returns the number of positive integers less than $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$.)

Now $\varphi (8)=4$.  Hence $5^4\cong1\pmod8.$

Use this to reduce the exponent: $133=4×33+1\implies5^{133}=(5^4)^{33}\cdot 5\cong5\pmod8$.